# Fill list of zero numbers under conditions in a nested list

Tags: python, list

This is a question I met in interview yesterday, so I cannot provide link to the original question here

Here is the description:

> I am given an array of integers like this [0,2,3],[1,0,0] where zeros
> stand for missing parts that I need to fill with the following
> conditions:
>
> 1. I am also given a number k, which means every number $a_{i}$ choose to fill is between 1 and k
> 2. After filling the number, the list should be in this order: a1<=a2<=a3...<=an(but I should not change the order of the index, which means I cannot fill in a bunch of numbers and sort the list)

Here is what I have done yesterday:

```
list1 = []
#%%
k = 3
a = [0,2,3]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 0:
        for j in range(1,k+1):
            a[i] = j
            print('a,',a)
            print('list1:',list1)
            if a[0] > a[1]:
                continue
            else:
                print(a)
                rv = 0
                for m in range(1,(len(a)-1)):
                    if a[m] <= a[m+1]:
                        rv+=1
                if rv == len(a) - 2:
                    print('value',a)
                    print('before;',list1)
                    list1.append(a.copy())
                    print('after',list1)
```

This can only solve list with one zero number, so anybody could help me solve the problem?

Extra explanation:

Answer (score 0):

If you want a short solution and your only conditions are the fill numbers are between 1 and `k` and each fill number has to be equal to or greater than the last fill number this will work:

```
k = 5
a = [0 , 2, 3, 0]
answer = list(map(lambda i: 1 if i==0 else i, a))
```

This obviously plays on the fact that all the fill numbers can be equal. If you want a more complete and verbose solution with increasing fill numbers you should keep track of the current/last fill number outside of your loop like so:

```
k = 5
last_fill = 1
a = [0, 1, 2, 0]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 0:
        if last_fill > k:
            print("Value out of k range!")
            break
        a[i] = last_fill
        last_fill += 1
```

Rereading through your question, I'm a little unsure if you would like the entire list to be sorted at the end or not. That being said, you can use `sort` to take care of any sorting such as in the above `answer = list(map(lambda i: 1 if i==0 else i, a)).sort()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks to your reply. I think i need to explain more about the question, it is not about sorting, the question tells me that i cannot change the index order of the original list

Comment: @SongCalderoneZhang ah. So position in the list must be preserved for all non-zero elements. If that's the case the solution using a lambda function works.